# How to change the order of group by column in sp list view

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula

I have a calculated column created in one of the Sharepoint list, here is the formula: =

```
IF(DaysDifference<0,"Overdue",IF(DaysDifference<=7," 7",IF(DaysDifference<=15,"15",IF(DaysDifference<=30,"30","Over 30"))))
```

I have then added group by this column for a view, below is the screenshot:
[image]
[image]

the return type of this calculated column is free text.
Is it possible to change the group by column order?
Currently its showing Overdue, Over 30, 30,15 and 7.
How can it be changed to follow this order: Overdue, 7, 15, 30, Over 30? Is this possible to do?

Please advise, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "group by" is text, so if the alphabetical order does not work for your data, you can add something that is alphabetical. (letters or spaces maybe)

Option one, add a sorting prefix:  (A. B. etc.)

```
A. Overdue
B. 7
C. 14
```

I.e.

```
IF(DaysDifference<0,"A. Overdue",IF(DaysDifference<=7,"B. 7"  ...
```

Another option, add spaces (indent):  (underlines typed below to represent spaces)

```
___Overdue
__7
_15
_30
Over 30
```

I.e.

```
IF(DaysDifference<0,"  Overdue",IF(DaysDifference<=7,"  7"  ...
```

Comment: Option 1 was perfect, thanks a lot again Mike.